# Can't GROUP BY with first unique item in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two MySQL tables:
**product**

[image: product table]

**photo**

[image: photo table]

Then I do INNER JOIN

```
SELECT * 
FROM product 
INNER JOIN photo 
    ON product.productID = photo.productID
```

[image: Result of INNER JOIN of these tables]

But I need only one raw per unique product ID

[image: What I need]

If I try:

```
SELECT * 
FROM product 
INNER JOIN photo 
    ON product.productID = photo.productID 
ORDER BY product.productID
```

It returns error

> Expression #38 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'photo.photoID' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

The problem is photoID column. There are few photos per one product, but I need table with only first photo per product.

Can I do it with MYSQL tools like WHERE for example?

Thanks!

Comment: If I try GROUP BY it gives mistake.. MySQL's isn't making a mistake.. You are making the mistake using GROUP BY in a invalid way.. Besides MySQL protected you from invalid results.

Comment: You have **products** and **photos** - But you want the first **meeting**?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL select only rows with max value on a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745609/sql-select-only-rows-with-max-value-on-a-column)

Comment: Please define "first meeting".  SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no such thing as a "first" row in a table or subset of rows.  You need a column that specifies the ordering.

Comment: What is the query that you are using? It seems that you just need `MIN(photoID)` in your SELECT clause.

Comment: I use this SELECT * FROM product INNER JOIN photo ON product.productID=photo.productID

Comment: Edit your question and add the query that is returning the error, the one with the group by.

Comment: Each table should have a unique ID. Why would you allow a product table to have multiple instance of a product ID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use *Aggregate function* clause,you need to use `GROUP BY` on no-Aggregate column.

Making a subquery to find the `MIN` `photoID`. then `JOIN` on another subquery

You can try this.

```
SELECT p.*,T.* FROM 
(
 SELECT productID,MIN(photoID) 'photoID'
 FROM photo
 GROUP BY productID
) T 
INNER JOIN (
 SELECT DISTINCT productID,name
 FROM product
) p ON p.productID = T.productID
```

*sqlfiddle : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/97a87d/12*

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!